# given a web URL how to convert it for PhoneGap both Android and iPhone?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

i am new to PhoneGap..i have just started with the basics..10 days before..

please tell me what is the procedure to change a given web URL as a android application and iphone application.

say for example stackoverflow.com/

please guide me...

**EXPECTING FOR AN APT SOLUTION**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find that in the  main activity (.java file) of your android project.

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

For iOS you will find it in the  AppDelegate.m file

```
self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";
```

Comment: well,manish kumar this was not what i actually asked for...i meant any specific format...and guidelines to be followed???

Comment: Can you please explain what is it that you actually want to do

Comment: thank you for the response,i want to convert a webpage to an android and ios application

Comment: you can take the resources(html,css,js) of that page and wrap it up with phonegap(place it in the www folder).

Comment: yeah.. but you then need to check the UI as it might not be optimised acc to the different phone screen sizes

Comment: see,to be specific...a webpage has n number of java script pages and style sheets...and which to select and what to do?